# How to get iOS 11 drag and drop working on the iPhone

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11

I've been trying out the new iOS 11 drag and drop feature. It's great, but it works only on iPad. Apple claims that it works also on the iPhone, but I can't get it working there? Is Apple's claim false, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225329/how-to-enable-uidraginteraction-on-custom-uiviews-for-iphone ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but no answer there is accepted, plus the answer doesn't explain _why_ I had so much trouble getting this to work. My answer does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're installing a UIDragInteraction object on some view, right? Well, by default, that drag interaction's `isEnabled` property is `false` on an iPhone (in accordance with the device-dependent value of the `isEnabledByDefault` class property).

So to switch on drag and drop on the iPhone, just set the drag interaction's `isEnabled` to true when you create it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dragger = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    self.dragView.addInteraction(dragger)
    dragger.isEnabled = true // for iPhone: presto, we've got drag and drop!
}
```

Similarly for a table view or collection view, as pointed out by the other answer, you would need to set its `dragInteractionEnabled` to `true`, as it too is `false` by default on an iPhone.

Comment: This helped a lot. I was missing the `isEnabled = true` because I thought it was true by default and it wasn't working on iPhone.

Comment: @IvanCantarino Yes, that's exactly what's so tricky: the defaults are different on iPad and iPhone. An interesting design decision by Apple.

Comment: whaaaat?! it took me hours to find it out... :/ no mention about it anywhere in documentation nor in WWDC videos. Everything good in playground and nothing on simulator/real device :D so weeeeird

Answer (score 10):

With Swift 4 and iOS 11, according to your needs, you can pick one of the following ways in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Allow drag and Drop interactions for `UITableView` on iPhone

`UITableView` has a property called `dragInteractionEnabled`. `dragInteractionEnabled` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2909064-draginteractionenabled):

```
var dragInteractionEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

> A Boolean value indicating whether the table view supports drags and drops between apps.

> The default value of this property is `true` on iPad and `false` on iPhone. Changing the value to `true` on iPhone makes it possible to drag content from the table view to another app on iPhone and to receive content from other apps.

The following code shows how to use `dragInteractionEnabled` in order to allow drag and drop interactions for `UItableView` on iPhone:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* ... */

        tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    }

}
```

---

### #2. Allow drag and drop interactions for `UICollectionView` on iPhone

`UICollectionView` has a property called `dragInteractionEnabled`. `dragInteractionEnabled` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/2909041-draginteractionenabled):

```
var dragInteractionEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

> A Boolean value indicating whether the collection view supports drags and drops between apps.

> The default value of this property is `true` on iPad and `false` on iPhone. Changing the value to `true` on iPhone makes it possible to drag content from the collection view to another app on iPhone and to receive content from other apps.

The following code shows how to use `dragInteractionEnabled` in order to allow drag and drop interactions for `UICollectionView` on iPhone:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* ... */

        collectionView?.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    }

}
```

---

### #3. Allow drag and drop interactions for `UIImageView` on iPhone

`UIDragInteraction` has a property called `isEnabled`. `isEnabled` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteraction/2891015-isenabled):

```
var isEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the drag interaction responds to touches and is allowed to participate in a drag activity.

The following code shows how to use `isEnabled` in order to allow drag interaction in addition to drop interaction for `UIImageView` on iPhone:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDragInteractionDelegate, UIDropInteractionDelegate {

    let imageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyImage")
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = view.bounds
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
        imageView.addInteraction(dropInteraction)

        let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
        dragInteraction.isEnabled = true
        imageView.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
    }

    /* ... */

}
```